# How to fix the timeout exception in angularJs?

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, timeout

I try to do some processing that take time, and suddenly the server returns me a timeOut exception.

Since my controller, I call the generate method that calls a service, and this service calls my class where there is the method that does the processing.
What is the solution in your opinion?

```
    vm.afficher = function() {

            vm.details = [];

            var x = vm.applicationField;
            if (x === undefined || x === null) {
                x = 'off';
            }

            FacturationSvc.generate({
                selectedDt : new Date(vm.selectedDt),
                applicationField : x
            }).$promise.then(function(resp) {
                vm.details = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(resp));
                vm.table.check = true;
            });
        }
```

vm is the instance of the controller.

```
       @RequestMapping("/facturations")
       @Controller
       public class FacturationController {
           private FacturationSvc facturationSvc; 

       @Autowired
       public FacturationController(FacturationSvc svc, UserSvc userSvc) {
          super();
          this.facturationSvc = svc;
        }

       @RequestMapping(value = "/generate/{selectedDt}/applicationName/{applicationField}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
       @ResponseBody
       public List<Facturation> generate(@PathVariable Date selectedDt,@PathVariable String applicationField) throws NoSuchFieldException{          
            return facturationSvc.facturer(selectedDt,applicationField);
        }  
       }
```

Comment: Can you show the `FacturationSvc` service code.

Comment: I posted it below